# How to add new key-value pair in secrets manager without impacting existing key and values in aws CDK

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-secrets-manager

I have created aws stack in python which create new secret in secrets manager. When I execute the code, stack created successfully and given secret and all provided keys-values listed successfully. Below is the code.

```
templated_secret = asm.Secret(self, "abzzzz11", 
description="ddddd",secret_name="hahahah",
        generate_secret_string=asm.SecretStringGenerator(
            secret_string_template=json.dumps({"username1": "", "password1": "","password2": "hello-world-prod2"}),
            generate_string_key="qwe"                
        )
   )
```

I have below two question:

**Question 1:** After creating secrets, values will be changed against keys for dev or stage environment. Now a new Key and value needs to be added for same secret. But after adding new values in my code when I execute the stack then it replace all the values. So is it possible that system only add those values which does not exist on aws secret manager?

**Question 2:**  I am unable to understand the purpose/use of ***generate_string_key*** in above code. I read the aws documentation but unable to understand the purpose of this field. So please help me to understand the usage of this field.